# When did Kakinoki Kinsuke used a kite to enter the Nagoya castle

Tags: japan, 18th-century

From different online sources I can find that the Japanese thief Kakinoki Kinsuke used a kite to fly over the wall of the Nagoya castle to steal certain golden parts of a statue.
The thing I can not find is, *when* he performed this theft. Does anyone know the year approximately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a rough translation of a page in Spanish:

> In **1712**, it is said that a thief named Kakinoki Kinsuke used a large kite to be transported to the top of Nagoya Castle. There, under cover of darkness, Kinsuke stole scales of a few gold dolphins.

And another page:

> In **1712**, a thief named Kakinoki Kinsuke is said to have used a large kite to carry himself to the top of Nagoya Castle. There, under the cover of darkness, Kinsuke stole the scales from a pair of golden dolphin.

I think it's safe to say that it occurred in 1712 during the Edo period.

### Sources

- http://www.batoco.org/barriletes/historia.html
- http://www.aka.kite.org/events/convention/2011-convention-forms/doc_details/403-articles-of-incorporation?tmpl=component
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagoya_Castle
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edo_period